# What do I need to connect 1/2 and 3/8 vinyl tubing?

Tags: plumbing, vinyl, fitting, pipe-fitting

I am just trying to connect an 1/2” vinyl tubing ([this one](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Everbilt-1-2-in-I-D-x-5-8-in-O-D-x-10-ft-Clear-Vinyl-Tubing-T10006010/304185142)) to a smaller 3/8” version.

I got [this 1/2” to 3/8” barb reducer](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Apollo-1-2-in-x-3-8-in-Brass-PEX-B-Barb-Reducing-Coupling-APXC1238/301541086) but it’s way too small and doesn’t fit.

Why?

Which part do I need instead?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The device you have linked to is for PEX pipe, which needs special crimpers. It is not deigned for vinyl tubing.

You need one of these:
[barb hose reducer](https://www.homedepot.com/p/LTWFITTING-3-8-in-x-1-2-in-I-D-Brass-Hose-Barb-Reducer-Splicer-Fittings-25-Pack-HF3913R080625/313389279)
[image: barb hose reducer]

(Admittedly, the link is for a set of 25, but a single wuold surely be obtainable.)

You will also need hose clamps.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience (as a brewer), when mating a barb to tubing and everything is sized properly, it takes some significant effort to get the tubing on the barb. This is by design, so that you get a leak-free seal (usually in conjunction with a hose clamp).

Some strategies that might be helpful:

- Soften the vinyl tubing by heating the end in boiling water before attempting to insert the barb.
- Use a utility knife to cut a bevel around the inside of the end of the tubing (effectively increasing the inside diameter to make it a bit easier to get the barb started).
- Pre-stretch the end of the tubing with something slightly smaller than the barb; perhaps something that has tapered thickness.

If I ever need to remove the tubing from a barb, I am almost never successful in pulling it off. I usually end up having to cut the tubing off of the barb, losing an inch of tubing in the process.

Comment: He said that the fitting is too small, not too large.